# Extract table data from the hyperlinks in a column on a website using UI Path

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

So I have a website which has table data (4 columns and 50 rows per page and 10 to 15 pages of data and I can navigate through each page to scrape and get this table data into an excel)

My use case is, there is a column within this table which has hyperlinks "details" which clicked there is a page which contains some table data. I want this data to be copied to excel.

I tried multiple workflows but no luck unfortunately.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you break this issue down into what is really important and adding some images showing what you tried so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have this table at `index.html`:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Details</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td><a href="jan.html">Details</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td><a href="feb.html">Details</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And this table in each details page (`jan.html`, `feb.html`):

```
<table id="myTable2">
  <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Revenue</td>
    <td>100,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Profit</td>
    <td>10,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

First, open the page and get the table using the `Use Application/Browser` activity and an `Extract Table Data` activity:

[image: Snippet of the program showing the activities used]

The `Extract Table Data` automatically saves the URL to an extra column:

[image: Preview of table data to be extracted]

Loop through each row of the table using the `For Each Row in Data Table` activity, go to the linked page using the `Go To URL` activity, and get the next table using another `Extract Data Table` activity:

[image: Snippet of the program showing the activities used]

Depending on how you want to display the results in Excel, you'll probably then want to use a [`Write DataTable to Excel` activity](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/other/latest/user-guide/write-range-x). If you can provide more information in your question about what the output should be, this answer could be expanded this answer to include that.

Comment: Hey @etskinner, thanks for the answer, I was able to figure this out and did the exact flow you showed me, thanks for your time :)